# Cannot find image file to attach using ActionMailer on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am trying to attach an image to an email using ActionMailer on Rails 4. In the /app folder, I have a mailer called 'UserMailer.' Here is the code in the mailer:

```
def welcome_email(user)

    @user = user
    @url = 'http://www.powerproject.com'
    attachments["powerpuff-girls.jpg"] = File.read('powerproject/app/assets/images/powerpuff-girls.jpg')

    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Welcome to Power Project!", reply_to: "powerprjct@gmail.com")
end
```

The mailer itself works fine when the attachment line is omitted. However, when I run this code, I get the error "No such file or directory." The image file is stored in app/assets/images.

Comment: try to use this only File.read('assets/powerpuff-girls.jpg')

Comment: I'd prefer using absolute path, like `File.read Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/powerpuff-girls.jpg')`